# devcon can't separate two devices when using the find command

Tags: batch-file, devcon

I am trying to disable one my graphics cards, but I am have some issues trying to only disable one. When I type.

```
devcon find PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_05E3&SUBSYS_0F3919F1&REV_A1\4&FA060A&0&0009
```

I get
`PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0FBC&SUBSYS_31021462&REV_A1\4&B7B0A11&0&0108: High Definition Audio Controller
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_05E3&SUBSYS_0F3919F1&REV_A1\4&FA060A&0&0009: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 285
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1380&SUBSYS_31021462&REV_A2\4&B7B0A11&0&0008: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti
3 matching device(s) found.
'DEV_05E3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'SUBSYS_0F3919F1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'FA060A' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'0009' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am afraid if I enter in `devcon disable PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_05E3&SUBSYS_0F3919F1&REV_A1\4&FA060A&0&0009`

it will turn off both my graphics cards at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote:

```
devcon disable "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_05E3&SUBSYS_0F3919F1&REV_A1\4&FA060A&0&0009"
```

or

Escape all the `&` with `^` :

```
 devcon disable PCI\VEN_10DE^&DEV_05E3^&SUBSYS_0F3919F1^&REV_A1\4^&FA060A^&0^&0009
```

Comment: Nope still did not work. By the way I am using windows 10 pro 64 bit I don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: i found out what to do you had to shorten it to devcon disable "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_05E3&SUBSYS_0F3919F1&REV_A1"